# Экспорт данных из MySQL в xls-файл

Tags: xls, php, excel, mysql

Доброго дня/вечера.

Хотел бы создать xls (excel) файл, с помощью PHP, в который бы записал данные из mysql, чтобы там были:

```
// 2я строка, колонка B: время
// 5я стока, колонка C, фраза: привет, я работаю
// 8я и ниже - результат запроса mysql
mysql_query("SELECT `name`,`fam`,`tel` FROM `table`");
// name в колонку А, fam в колонку B, tel в колонку С
```

Т.е. я так понимаю, файл создастся, и нужно будет как-то его сохранить. Не открывать, не пытаться его открыть, просто создать с нужными данными и все.

p.s. К сожалению, натыкаюсь на темы mysql -> csv, что как бы не то. Или попадаются гигантские библиотеки, которые или не скачать, или не работают, еще попадаются средства по выводу данных из xls. Можете подсказать рабочую команду?

Comment: > можете подсказать рабочую команду?

`die();`
----------------------------
а по сути - гиганские библиотеки применять и нужно!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Кирпичами прошу не кидать!

1. Ищем в яндексе. [Находим](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/list/changesets?ProjectName=phpexcel)
2. Нажимаем `download`, берем из архива содержимое `trunk/Classes/`
3. В php файл вставляем следующее:

   ```
   require_once 'PHPExcel.php';
   $phpexcel = new PHPExcel();
   $page = $phpexcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
   $page->setCellValue("B2", "время");
   $page->setCellValue("C5", "привет, я работаю");
   $page->setCellValue("A8", "результат запроса mysql");
   $page->setTitle("Test");
   $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($phpexcel, 'Excel2007');
   $objWriter->save("test.xlsx");
   ```

Думаю, алгоритм понятен. Кстати давно хотел поднять тему связанную с данным решением.