# Работа PHPExcel с картинками

Tags: phpexcel, php, изображения

Используя одно решение мне данное свыше: [Экспорт данных из MySQL в xls-файл](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/152812/181472)

Использую `PHPExcel`, так сказать в простом виде, ест-но хочется чуть больше. Определенным циклом вставляю данные в файл, очень хочется вставить туда картинки. Подскажите как с это можно сделать, и можно ли вообще используя `PHPExcel`? Я так понимаю сначала нужно растянуть ячейки до определенной ширины/высоты, а затем вставить туда картинки определенной ширины/высоты.

Comment: Здравствуйте. Как узнать названия ячеек, в которых присутствуют изображения?

Comment: @murash Если у Вас возник новый вопрос, пожалуйста, задайте его при помощи кнопки «[Задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)». Если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/56835)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Поиск - наше всё!

[Картинки](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/271473)

```
$gdImage = imagecreatefromjpeg('images/officelogo.jpg');
// Add a drawing to the worksheetecho date('H:i:s') . " Add a drawing to the worksheet\n";
$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing();
$objDrawing->setName('Sample image');$objDrawing->setDescription('Sample image');
$objDrawing->setImageResource($gdImage);
$objDrawing->setRenderingFunction(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::RENDERING_JPEG);
$objDrawing->setMimeType(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::MIMETYPE_DEFAULT);
$objDrawing->setHeight(150);
$objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());
```

[Работа с ячейками](http://clock.co.uk/tech-blogs/phpexcel-cheatsheet) (выставление высоты, ширины и авто ширины):

```
// ширина
$sheet->getColumnDimension("A")->setWidth(40);
// высота
$sheet->getRowDimension('1')->setRowHeight(40);
// авто высота
$sheet->getRowDimension(1)->setRowHeight(-1);
// авто ширина
$sheet->getColumnDimension("A")->setAutoSize(true);
```

Comment: @Nick Volynkin готово

Answer (score 2):

Вот еще не маловажный момент. Надо указать объект самого листа

```
$objDrawing->setWorksheet($page->getActiveSheet());
```

Answer (score 0):

Примеры чертовски хороши. Прогресс скажем так 2/3, что уже здорово. К сожалению часть не увидел

```
//устанавливаем ширину 200px для определенного столбца
// ура! работает
$page->getColumnDimension("B")->setWidth(28);

// перебираем записи из бд. $stroka - 10, прибавляем по 3
// опять ура! работает. высота строки нужная
$page->getRowDimension($stroka)->setRowHeight(200);
$page->setCellValue("B".$stroka."", "".$massiv["art"]."");
$page->setCellValue("D".$stroka."", "".$massiv["raz"]."");

// с картинками беда. просто не работает
$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
$objDrawing->setPath("img/close.gif"); // ./img/close.gif - тоже не работает
$objDrawing->setCoordinates("A".$stroka."");
```